# Asp.net Resource not working on Master Page

Tags: asp.net

I've added Names and Values to the Resource file and using
    `<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, keyName%>" />` but it's not working only the keys are displayed and not the corresponding text. I've cleaned the project re-run debug many times and other troubleshooting but still no luck. Anything am missing when it comes to resources on Master Pages.

NB: This is working fine for other pages.

Comment: So, you've got a child page with that code and its displaying the value text properly, but when you put that code in the master page you only see the key names?

Comment: Strange enough I tried other keys and they are working. I've tried changing the key name but still.

Comment: So, its only a single key that is not working?  Sounds like a corrupt resource file.

Comment: Sorry, actually this was being caused by localization tool. It wasn't loading the changes edited using VS.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed! :)